# Python script to login to a remote server and access Cassandra database

Tags: python, bash, cassandra

I have to write a python script that logs on using ssh to a remote server and access the Cassandra database there . I am using paramiko but after login in to the server , it doesn't connect to Cassandra and script hangs .

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect('10.65.XXX.XX', username='sinha.aman', password='', key_filename='/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cqlsh 10.65.XXX.XX 9042 -u ABC123 -p 12345')
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('ls')
print(stdout.readlines())
ssh.close()
```

Comment: is cqlsh running if connect manually to the machine?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the script waits from some user input since you're opening a cqlsh session?

Try adding the -e flag to cqlsh command:

```
cqlsh -e 'select * from test.emp'
```

Change accordingly to your script.

Check also `cqlsh --help` for -e flag.

> ```
> -e EXECUTE, --execute=EXECUTE
>                         Execute the statement and quit.
> ```

Answer (score 1):

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cqlsh 10.65.XXX.XX 9042 -u ABC123 -p 12345')
```

Here it is opening a cqlsh prompt, which is expecting a command to be executed, not returning any output.

Script is waiting for an input command. We have to pass cqlsh command to get the output.

By adding "-e help" or any other command will solve the issue.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command('cqlsh 10.65.XXX.XX 9042 -u ABC123 -p 12345 **-e help** ')
```

For better understanding, execute the command manually in remote server, where you will see a cqlsh prompt waiting for command.

For all the cqlsh commands please refer
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql-oss/3.x/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCommandsTOC.html